# Button Event isn't displaying value until 2nd click (vb6)

Tags: tcp, vb6, winsock, commandbutton

I created a tcp connection in vb6 to grab the weight off of a scale and display that weight after pressing a button. The problem is that the weight is not displayed until the SECOND (2nd) click of the button, not the first. I have set a break point in various spots and upon the first click of the button, it takes me to that break point, so I know the event is firing as it should, but nothing is displayed until the 2nd click. I have done a bunch of research but can't seem to find anyone with the exact problem (or solution).

```
Public tcpC As New Winsock
'Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Private Sub CFixPicture_Close()
 tcpC.Close
End Sub

Private Sub CFixPicture_Initialize()
 tcpC.LocalPort = 0
 tcpC.Connect "192.168.0.1", 8000
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_click()

 On Error GoTo errHandler
 Dim strData As String

 tcpC.SendData "S" & vbCrLf
 tcpC.GetData strData
 Text1.Caption = "Weight: " & strData
Exit Sub

 errHandler:
    MsgBox "error:" & Err.Description
End Sub
```

Comment: Your GetData call is probably executing before there is any data to get. See the DataArrival event.

Comment: I changed the name of the sub to the dataArrival event but still no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am making an assumption that your code is in the form and you are just declaring a new object of type Winsock. My code declares a Winsock variable using the keyword WithEvents to get access to the events raised by the Winsock object. The particular event you're interested in is DataArrival. It is fired by the Winsock control when data is received. I moved setting the text to this event. Also, you cannot use WithEvents and "As New" (you really don't want to use As New anyway), so I create the object before I set the properties in the CFixPicture_Initialize() method. Finally, I added setting the object to nothing after closing it.

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents tcpC As Winsock

Private Sub CFixPicture_Close()
    tcpC.Close
    Set tcpP = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub CFixPicture_Initialize()

    Set tcpC = New Winsock
    tcpC.LocalPort = 0
    tcpC.Connect "192.168.0.1", 8000

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_click()

    On Error GoTo errHandler
    Dim strData As String

    tcpC.SendData "S" & vbCrLf

    'there is no data here yet - moved to the DataArrival event
    'tcpC.GetData strData
    'Text1.Caption = "Weight: " & strData

Exit Sub

errHandler:
    MsgBox "error:" & Err.Description
End Sub

Private Sub tcpC_DataArrival(ByVal bytesTotal As Long)
    Dim strData As String

    tcpC.GetData strData
    Text1.Caption = "Weight: " & strData

End Sub
```

Comment: Great! thanks for your help @jac. The button started registering the first click. The only thing I would like to mention is that I removed the tcpc.close command because it was throwing me error 91. For some reason the tcp connection was already closing itself out so it didn't like me closing it again. Thanks!